# Understanding of Hadoop parallel processing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I'm very new in Hadoop and recently configured Hadoop inside Virtual box with Ubuntu, here Name Node and Resource Manager are configured independent machines and also 3 seprate datanodes, and one client node.

After read some more articles, I got an understanding mapreduce jobs are running on multiple nodes in parallel,

For my understanding, I have written a Mapreduce program and access the hostName of the system as key in map function, this is for I want to understand the parallelism

I have loaded the data to Hdfs, 200MB of data with 64 MB block size, confirmed 3 datanodes having blocks

After exported the jar and run from client using yarn jar as well as hadoop jar, my expectation is it would be get the three datanodes name in side the reducer, but it shows Client system Name

Please can you explain how this execution ( Hadoop jar) works, Is it run my mapreduce jar in all three nodes, if then why it shows the client host name instead of three datanodes

Comment: add the code of mapper and reducer, your input and expected output

Comment: It should get the NodeManager name, which very well could only be a single machine... If you're not reading any HDFS data and only getting a hostname, there's no reason to parallelize the operation